# What are the consequences of a throwing swap() for a type?

Tags: c++, c++17, swap

The [A swap function must not fail](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c84-a-swap-function-must-not-fail) rule of CppCoreGuidelines says:

> `swap` is widely used in ways that are assumed never to fail and programs cannot easily be written to work correctly in the presence of a failing `swap`. The standard-library containers and algorithms will not work correctly if a swap of an element type fails.

The [Make swap noexcept](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-swap-noexcept) rule of CppCoreGuidelines says:

> A `swap` must not fail. If a `swap` tries to exit with an exception, it’s a bad design error and the program had better terminate.

Consider a class `C`, for which a noexcept move constructor, noexcept move assignment operator and noexcept `swap()` cannot be implemented. Its copy constructor and copy assignment operator are `noexcept(false)`, therefore `std::swap<C>()` is `noexcept(false)` too. Should a `friend` `swap()` for this class be declared `noexcept` anyway so as to terminate in case of an exception and avoid the "bad design error"?

The described class `C` is a rare case. However, C++03 classes, which define a destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator, lack noexcept move operations. A custom `swap()` for such classes may be non-throwing, though not declared `noexcept`. If they don't have a custom `swap()`, the `std::swap()` specialization calls their copy operations, and so can throw. Do such classes commit the "bad design error"?

Can classes with a throwing `swap()` be used in standard-library containers and algorithms? Does the standard specify that `swap()` must not throw exceptions or be `noexcept(true)` for some standard-library functionality to work? If some parts of the standard library do not work correctly when `swap()` throws, this must be spelled out in the standard somewhere. The standard library often relies on the destructor to be `noexcept`; falls back on exception-safe copying when the move operations are `noexcept(false)`. I wonder where `swap()`'s exception specification stands in this regard.

*EDIT [for those who cannot imagine a class with a throwing `swap()`]*: my class `C` (implemented before C++11 by someone else) is externally, optionally reference-counted. A specific object of this class `C` is reference-counted if a global container contains its address (`this`). When a reference-counted object is copied or moved into or swapped with a not-reference-counted object (or vice versa), the reference counts have to be changed. Manipulating reference counts is very complicated. Not only does it (optionally) allocate memory, but performs other operations that are more likely to fail than `operator new`. Wrapping each object into a `unique_ptr` would cause a huge overhead for the most common not-reference-counted case. Of course, such classes are not commonplace, but I think there are enough of throwing `swap()`s around to deserve some consideration.

*EDIT of the previous EDIT*: special member functions **must** (conditionally) change reference counts because they depend on the object's value. Each object contains a handle to an external resource, which is optionally reference counted. So when the value of a reference-counted object is changed during the copying/moving/swapping with a non-reference-counted object, the reference count of its previous handle has to be decreased and the reference count of its new handle (from the other object) has to be increased.

Comment: In practice, there isn't really any reason to use a type that has throwing move semantics. Make the type unmoveable instead and wrap it in a movable handler. It can be as simple as a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: If your type has throwing move but is also copiable, some containers are designed to work around the throwing move semantics by always using copies instead. You get correct behavior and you maintain exception guaranties, but you lose out in performance. I'm not sure if this is true of *all* containers and algorithms, but at least `std::vector` works this way.

Comment: I'm curious, what type of situation do you have where your move operations cant be `noexcept(true)`.  Moving should only involve copy pointers and setting them to null in the moved from object.

Comment: I think you're asking too many questions here and it's unclear what you really want to know. Can you rephrase your question to unambiguously state a single question?

Comment: Edited the question - added my specific use case to answer the comments. I am most interested in whether or not to mark the copy operations and the custom `swap()` as noexcept, even if they may (however unlikely) throw in practice.

Comment: @vedg: "*I think there are enough of throwing swap()s around to deserve some consideration.*" The core C++ guidelines are for modern C++ programs. The define what represents reasonable functionality. Legacy, pre-C++11, idioms are not *supposed* to be represented, unless they actually represent good design. You're talking about a class with bad design that might have been the only way to do things at one point, but it definitely isn't OK now.

Comment: @vedg: Also, I updated my answer to show that you can implement this `swap` without throwing. They may not have implemented it that way, and the overall implementation could have been written in a way to preclude doing it, bu there is no *conceptual* reason why you can't.

Answer (score 2):

> Its copy constructor and copy assignment operator are `noexcept(false)`, therefore `std::swap<C>()` is `noexcept(false)` too.

This is where you run into a problem.

A type with a throwing copy constructor is a type such that copying the internal state of an object requires performing a throwing operation. If you copy construct a `std::vector`, the new `vector` has no state yet. Therefore, it must be able to allocate memory (if the other `vector` stores stuff), which is potentially throwing.

A move operation requires that the moved-from object be put into some valid state, while absconding with any resources it may possess. As such, a type with a throwing move is one where putting it into a valid-but-unspecified state requires performing a throwing operation.

Many `std::list` implementations have a head node, which is a node that always exists, which is the node before the first and the node after the last. Some `std::list` implementations heap-allocate this node. An invariant of such `list` implementations is that the pointer to the head node cannot be nullptr. Such implementations must, on move, allocate memory for the moved-from object's head node. This is a throwing operation.

Swapping however involves two objects, *both of which* are currently in a valid state, and afterwards both of which will be in the same valid states that the other one was in. There is nothing about this process that could reasonably *require* performing a throwing operation.

Oh sure, if you do the 3-copy/move method of swapping, you could get throwing operations. But for any type which has a throwing copy&move, I cannot imagine a circumstance where you *cannot* implement a non-throwing `swap`.

And it will undoubtedly be a *faster* `swap` implementation than the 3-copy/move method. A 3-copy/move implementation of `swap<vector>` has to copy 9 pointers, and null out 6 pointers. A direct implementation only has to write to 6 pointers, and null out nothing.

There is no reason to allocate memory on swap, since both objects have all the memory they need; that memory is simply in the wrong object. There is no reason to create other resources (like file handles, etc), since each object owns what the other object wants. Even in the case of `std::list`, `std::swap<std::list>` is defined to be `noexcept` regardless of implementation. It's just copying pointers around. Same for every container and every other standard library type; they are `noexcept` (in some cases, to the extent that any template arguments are nothrow swappable).

So even in the case of an object with throwing copy&move, `swap` should be able to be implemented in a non-throwing way.

The danger in making a throwing `swap` is that basically nobody will expect it. `swap` is *supposed* to be a safe operation.

> When a reference-counted object is copied or moved into or swapped with a not-reference-counted object (or vice versa), the reference counts have to be changed

Not on swap, they don't.

At the beginning of a `swap` operation, one of the objects is reference by X number of objects, and the other object has no reference count. At the end of the `swap` operation, one of the objects is referenced by X number of objects, and the other has no reference count. The number of references is the same after the swap as it is before. Which is which is beside the point: the reference count is the same.

If it's the same at the start as at the end, then there's no reason to modify it when swapping. It may currently be implemented to do so, but it does not *have to*.

---

> So when the value of a reference-counted object is changed during the copying/moving/swapping with a non-reference-counted object, the reference count of its previous handle has to be decreased and the reference count of its new handle (from the other object) has to be increased.

Let's look at a more concrete example. You have two objects, `a` and `b`. `a` has a pointer to a reference counted object `x` that has 3 references, and `b` has a pointer to a non-reference counted object `y`.

If you swap them, then `a` should have a pointer to a non-reference counted object `y`, and `b` should have a pointer to a reference counted object `x` with 3 references. That's what `swap` is supposed to mean: you take the value of the 2 objects and put them into the other one.

If this is what your code does, there is no reason why the reference counts in `x` and `y` need to be modified. They are the same at the start as they are at the end. How you achieve this doesn't matter; whatever you're doing to achieve it does not need to be able to throw. You're just shuffling numbers around.

If you are saying that the current "swap" code means that `a` pointers to `y` with 3 references, and `b` points to `x` with no references, then your "swap` function *is a lie*.

If this is the case, the consequences of a lying swap are that no standard library function which swaps things will make sense. `reverse`, `sort`, and many others will be broken. Not because of throwing, but because your "swap" operation is lying and "swapping" objects doesn't work right.

Comment: "There is no reason to allocate memory on swap, since both objects have all the memory they need; that memory is simply in the wrong object. "   Only if both objects are bound to the same allocator, otherwise it's entirely possible that each object cannot adopt the resources formerly owned by the other, and must allocate using its own allocator.  [`swap` if the allocators are unequal is NOT a safe operation, the Standard designates it as UB for standard containers.](https://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#9)

Comment: I feel that OP's case of "When a reference-counted object is copied or moved into or swapped with a not-reference-counted object" is categorically equivalent to having different allocators.

Comment: @BenVoigt the link is about requirements for standard library containers themselves: `The expression a.swap(b), for containers a and b ... shall exchange the values of a and b without invoking any move, copy, or swap operations on the individual container elements...` not for elements.

Comment: @dewaffled: Yes, I'm looking at the guarantees made by objects (containers) defined in the Standard Library.  When the two objects involved in swap have different allocations, there is not only no `noexcept` guarantee, the behavior is totally undefined.  "the behavior is undefined unless `a.get_­allocator() == b.get_­allocator()`".  So if Standard library objects (containers) have conditions on swap `noexcept` guarantee, it is not impossible that OP would also have conditions on `noexcept` for his own `swap`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: But it's not a condition on being `noexcept`; it's a condition on `swap` *working at all*. There is no `swap` in that case.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It's still a condition on it being `noexcept`.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Your edit concerning reference counts assumes there is no back-reference (although one assumes those would be weak references... but weak references still increment the reference count to the control block)

Comment: Added another EDIT into the question to explain why the reference counts must be manipulated by my class's special member functions. This answer argues that `swap()` should never throw. I am more interested and would be more convinced by what the standard says in this regard. Expanded the question's wording to this effect.

Comment: @vedg: "*Added another EDIT into the question to explain why the reference counts must be manipulated by my class's special member functions*" `swap` is not a special member function. You shouldn't lump it in with copy and move. Furthermore, there is no reason why swap *must* change reference counts, because the number of references *does not change*; only which object is doing the referencing. This is why `unique_ptr` is swappable: it doesn't change the number of objects referencing each pointer.

Comment: @vedg: I've elaborated on the use case you've described.

Comment: It's actually a disk reference counting. Only the objects, addresses of which are present in a global container, participate in the reference counting. If no such object contains a handle to a resource, then the resource is removed at the application shutdown. So swapping with a non-reference-counted object should decrease the refcount of the old reference-counted object's handle and increase the refcount of its new handle. I was hoping I wouldn't have to delve into this complexity in the swap() question. What does the standard say about `swap()` throwing/exception specification requirements?

Comment: @vedg: If you swap two objects, the other object has a reference to the handle. That's *what "swap" means:* you have exchanges the values of two objects. The other object references the handle; why should the count decrease when the number of objects referencing the handle *has not changed*?

Comment: @vedg: The scenario you seem to be outlining is one where `a.refcount()` is (for example) 3, then you do `swap(a, b)`, and `b.refcount()` is not 3. That is not a swap. This is no longer about "throwing swap"; this is about swap *meaning swap*.

Comment: The reference counts are not visible and don't matter to most users of the class. The low-level users that care insert the address of an object they want to be disk-reference-counted into the global table before its in-place construction, remove after its destruction (with RAII wrappers). `swap()` still means swapping because the data (handle) stored in the object is swapped and each member function call produces the expected result, regardless of the reference counting (or whether it is enabled or not for a given object).
In your example, `b` has no notion of a reference count at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Can classes with a throwing swap() be used in standard-library containers and algorithms?

The problem is throwing swap can result in unspecified state of the container.

For instance, if you are applying `sort` to vector it will be swapping its elements in the process. If you implement swap with assignment to temporary:

```
void swap(T& x, T& y)
{
    auto tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
}
```

and it will throw when assigning `y`, then you will have duplicated `y` value in the vector and lost `x` value if you catch the exception and it is implementation specific which value it will be, i.e. if it is invokes as `swap(v[i], v[j])` or `swap(v[j], v[i])`.

So, technically you can use throwing swap, but should discard all related  data if catching the exceptions.

Comment: Are you sure that the loss of strong exception safety guarantees is the worst possible consequence of a throwing `swap()`? If that is the case, I suppose the CppCoreGuidelines should say so to make the no-fail `swap()` requirement less uncompromising.

Comment: @vedg: The point of the C++ core guidelines is to give guidance on language best practices. Throwing `swap` is a terrible idea that you never need to actually do (and even in your supposed case, it's only there because of legacy pre-C++11 code), so the guideline itself is fine.